# Python - Matplotlib different color for different y values

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have been trying to plot some data using matplotlib. I am using:

```
plt.plot(x1Values, y1Values, color='green', linestyle='None', 
        marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=4)
```

Here x1Values is a list of names for example:

```
x1Values = ['alice', 'jordan', 'mike']
```

and y1Values is a list of binary tuples for example:

```
y1Values = [(2,3),(1,1),(4,5)]
```

Now the plot function mentioned above works basically as expected two points against each value on x axis, but plot is a bit cluttered, as my actual list sizes are ~100. which is why i want to avoid plt.label() function to label these points. The labels start overlapping, making the graphs messy and somewhat useless. What i want to be able to do is give different colors to these points. For example, on the graph, i want (alice,2) to be green, and (alice,3) to be red. likewise, (mike,4) to be green, and (mike,5) to be red, and if possible, (i dont have high hopes here, but if possible) I would want the overlapping point (jordan,1) and (jordan,1) to be some other color, say blue. But its fine if that is not achievable, as long as the rest is achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your answer too late so here's my approach, too:

I think, in general a scatter plot is more suitable for your situation.
As it allows you to set the color individually for every single point.
The implementation below, also paints overlapping results blue.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x1Values = ['alice', 'jordan', 'mike']
y1Values = [(2,3),(1,1),(4,5)]

xData = []
yData = []
cols = []
for counter, name in enumerate(x1Values):
    #Decide which point gets which color
    if (y1Values[counter][0] > y1Values[counter][1]):
        cols += ['r', 'g']
    elif (y1Values[counter][0] < y1Values[counter][1]):
        cols += ['g', 'r']
    else:
        cols += ['b', 'b']

    #adding names and values to the data for x and y Axes    
    xData += [name, name]
    yData += y1Values[counter]


myplot = plt.scatter(xData, yData, color=cols)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured the solution out, minutes after posting the question. Divided y values into two lists and plotted both of them individually, here`s the code:

```
y1Values = [i[0] for i in yValues]
y2Values = [i[1] for i in yValues]
plt.plot(x1Values, y1Values, color='black', linestyle='None', linewidth = 3, 
        marker='o', markerfacecolor='green', markersize=4)
plt.plot(x1Values, y2Values, color='black', linestyle='None', linewidth = 3, 
        marker='o', markerfacecolor='red', markersize=4)
```